# What is the path of a site collection relative to a subsite if they are named the same "http://root/site"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, site-collection, sub-site

I've been moving subsites into their own site collections and am now in the process of removing the old subsites. I know I can go through the UI in "Site Actions" -> "Sites and workspaces" to remove the subsites effectively. The current path for both sites are root/sitecollection and root/subsite, both with the same name.

Would SPWeb target the subsite and SPSite target the collection given they both have the same path? Is there a way to see this difference in powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsing from site collection -> subsite would actually take me to the new site collection that I created since I added a managed path entry when creating the new site collection of the same name.

To remove the subsite I temporarily deleted the managed path for root/sitecollection which forced root/subsite to become active again along that path. I was then free to remove the subsite via site settings or powershell.

Afterwards I re-added the managed path and the root/sitecollection became active. I only had to do this because both subsite and sitecollection were named and pathed the same.

Answer (score -1):

you can try ~sitecollection/path-in-root-site

Comment: Can you please add more details to this answer to make it helpful, it is not easy to understand what you are proposing